# Discord.js | JSON - Ticket system, bot does not create ticket channel

Tags: javascript, json, discord

my bot is not creating a ticket channel when a user is reacting to the emoji, the bot is only creating a ticket channel when I give my bot administrator rights within discord role itself.

What could be wrong in my code when user reacts to the emoji? Something missing, or permissions missing below? My bots ID 701327880046510080

And btw. on my discord I have given my bot all rights, but not administrator rights at the bottom of roles permissions.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
if(reaction.message.id == ticketid && reaction.emoji.name == '') {
            reaction.users.remove(user);
            const ticketChannel = reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.find(chan => chan.name === `ticket-${user.username}`)
            if (ticketChannel) return;
            reaction.message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${user.username}`, {
                parent: '701254271861260389',
                position: 1,
                permissionOverwrites: [
                    {
                        id: '701327880046510080',
                        allow: ["MANAGE_CHANNELS", "MANAGE_GUILD", "MANAGE_ROLES", "MANAGE_EMOJIS", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY", "MANAGE_MESSAGES", "SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
                    },
                    {
                        id: user.id,
                        allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"]
                    },
                    {
                        id: reaction.message.guild.roles.everyone,
                        deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]
                    },
                    {
                        id: '306893721725829121',
                        allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"]
                    }
                ],
```

Comment: @stayarthur is your bot above all the roles in the discord client? [random image](https://www.prostreamingsetup.com/wp-content/uploads/pages/guides/how-to-create-setup-and-manage-Discord/4.2.-Role-interference.png) but demonstrates what I mean?

Comment: @Gh0st i checked, yes my bot is at the top above all other roles and he got all permissions, the only button that is deactivated is the administrator button at the bottom in permissions

Answer (score 0):

It is most defintely a permission problem as you said it only works when you give the bot admin. It could also be because of the snippet below, you are allowing the permission but then denying it to everyone.

```
{
 id: reaction.message.guild.roles.everyone,
 deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]
 },
```

Comment: thanks, that helps me more. one more question, do you know by any chance why my users are able to create unlimited ticket channels when they react to the emoji? is there a way to restrict it to one channel at a time unless the user has closed the ticket again?

Comment: you would need a cooldown or some sort of role assigned to each ticket, just thinking of something quick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if/what errors you get with the `await` you will need to make sure that your listener is `async` so that may need to be added to code above this which based on the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166517/discord-js-my-users-are-able-to-create-unlimited-ticket-channels-when-they-reac/72179950) it should be.

```js
if (reaction.message.id == ticketid && reaction.emoji.name == '') {
    reaction.users.remove(user);
    const channelName = `ticket-${user.username}`;
    const ticketChannel = reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.find(chan => chan.name === channelName);
    if (ticketChannel) return;
    const newChannel = await reaction.message.guild.channels.create(channelName, {
        parent: '701254271861260389',
        position: 1,
        permissionOverwrites: [{
            id: reaction.message.guild.id,
            deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        }, {
            id: user,
            allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"],
        }, {
            id: '306893721725829121',
            allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"],
        }, {
            id: '701327880046510080',
            allow: ["MANAGE_CHANNELS", "MANAGE_GUILD", "MANAGE_ROLES", "MANAGE_EMOJIS", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY", "MANAGE_MESSAGES", "SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
        }],
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
    console.log(newChannel);
}
```

If the above fails it is likely a permission issue, just need to find out for sure what is preventing it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried it, it gave me those error logs: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
at RequestHandler.execute (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
method: 'post',
path: '/guilds/692091511101325332/channels',
 code: 50013,
 httpStatus: 403`

Comment: i went into the developer portal, and clicked oauth2, chosen in-app authorization, tried to give permissions which are needed for my bot, but when saving it gave me this error: Cannot have install fields on a private application

Comment: The oauth2 portal of the discord.dev website doesn't play a factor into this, That error is saying the code worked fine your bot just doesn't have the permissions to do something. Whose id is this `306893721725829121`? User name Tobi#3562?

Comment: ok. yes that is Tobi, i have lots of roles, I made Tobi admin with this role, he doesnt have "administrator" rights

Comment: Well not sure where it is but your bot is missing the permission to do something, I'd need to inspect the code more to see where that is, don't think its an intents issue cause its not throwing an intent error....what happens if you comment out the entire `permissionOverwrites` part of that code? Does it throw the error? If not, then add the `permissionOverwrites` back in one at a time and see when it throws the error.

Comment: So only thing I found is a couple syntax errors I also added some code for logging, can you give me the results when you run it https://pastebin.com/GJ4kFi9R just put it in a pastebin/sourcebin

Comment: thank you for checking! i tried right now, this is the full error log: [sourcebin](https://srcb.in/3cUFy7BVBv)

Comment: and about the embed, yes i just never really continue the embed because the ticket system didnt really work. but with the embed stuff i am familiar with